# iOS local notification that depends on live value

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have a local notification with an interval of an hour. But the displaying information is coming from a value which is basically a html parse result(just a string) and it's now in my main viewDidLoad method. That's why all the notification data is the same and not updating. The question is how i can make this process done automatically in the background on swift? (It should re-parse and update my string then display it as a local notification)

Thank you

Comment: For clarification, so once your notification is fired you want to check to make sure the notification being fired is the most up to date information?

Comment: yes it could be awesome

Comment: The issue is no extra code is fired when a notification is fired. You will need some type of back-end to push the most up to date information to the user.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I think I'm going for back{4}app